# .get() python json file discord bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, bots, leaderboard, keyerror

I have a json file that stores the ids, xp and level of who writes on my server.
I'm making a leaderboard to show the people who have most xp on my server,
however a keyerror appears:
    KeyError: '370034734186758173'

Could someone help me fixing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.get` would be used when accessing the `users` dictionary. You can add a second parameter to the call as the default (in case you don't find such a key), which in the first call you should output a empty dictionary, so that the second `.get` doesn't fail.

```
lb = list(map(lambda m: (m, users.get(m.id, {}).get("xp"), message.server.members))
```

Since you are making a list out of it, you may also want to try (the somewhat more pythonic) list comprehension (not that your line has anything wrong with it):

```
lb = [ (m, users.get(m.id, {}).get("xp") for m in message.server.members ]
```

Note that both approaches will return a None item when the get doesn't find the Key in the dictionary, you can ommit this using an `if` clause in the list comprehension:

```
lb = [ (m, users.get(m.id, {}).get("xp") for m in message.server.members if m.id in users ]
```

---

As a side note, I would add that you have included everything within the context manager clause (`with open():`), while only the line where you load its contents is necessary. It would be best practice to de-indent the rest of your code.

Answer (score 0):

So right off the back your friend was probably referring to the fact you could do something like this:
`lb = list(map(lambda m: (m, users.get(m.id, {'xp': 0}).get('xp')), message.server.members)]`

But as to why this works, you should first read the documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get

But I think you might prefer a list comprehension for what you're doing instead:
https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

for example you could rewrite how you get your `lb` variable like so:

`lb = [(member, users[member.id].get('xp')) for member in message.server.members if member.id in users]`

This is equivalent to writing the following:

```
lb = []
for member in message.server.members:
    # Check if the member is in your users list
    if member.id in users: 
        lb.append((member, users[member.id].get('xp')))
```